# Oracle query to count and group specific field

Tags: oracle

I have the following example table:

```
FIELD1     FIELD2      FIELD3
12345      888555      009999
12345      888555      327777
12345      888555      327777
54321      999666      334444
54321      999666      324444
55501      999333      005555
55501      999333      350000
55501      999333      890000
55501      999333      320000
```

Now, assuming FIELD1 and FIELD2 have always the same value, e.g. if FIELD1 = 12345 then FIELD2 will be always 888555, what I have to do is make a query where I count FIELD1 and FIELD2 occurencies when the first 2 digits of FIELD3 = 32 and when the first 2 digits of FIELD3 IS NOT 32.

In above case I should have as output:

```
FIELD1  FIELD2    FIELD3    COUNT
12345   888555    32            2
54321   999666    NOT32         1
54321   999666    32            1
55501   999333    32            1
55501   999333    NOT32         3
```

This query should do what I need:

```
select FIELD1, 
       FIELD2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(FIELD3, 1, 2) = '32' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FIELD3_EQU_32, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(FIELD3, 1, 2) = '32' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as FIELD3_NEQ_32
from TABLE where and FIELD3 IS NOT NULL
group by ORIG_ADDR, ORIG_IMSI order by ORIG_ADDR;
```

What I need now is output only a the fields with counter who exceeded a specifc threshold plus a part of FIELD2.
Something like:

```
HAVING ((FIELD3_EQU_32 > '10' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,3)='888')  
or (FIELD3_NEQ_32 > '5' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,3)='999')
or (FIELD3_NEQ_32 > '5' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,3)='777')
or (FIELD3_NEQ_32 > '15' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,3)='123')
etc...etc...)
```

Could someone help me to achieve that?
Thank you very much
Lucas

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Please construct a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) with your table and data and give us your desired output - I am unclear from your prose explanation! Leave me a comment when you have done this ('@' + my name - no space).

Comment: @Vérace thank you for reply, in my OP there is also the output I need. Basically, I have to split FIELD3 from value starting with 32 AND value that doesn't start with 32, count them and output if the count is higher than a specific value. The query I posted do the count and split and output all the cases. Now I need to apply to the query a filter to output only fields where the counter is higher then a specific value. e.g. (FIELD3_EQU_32 > '10' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,3)='888')  
or (FIELD3_NEQ_32 > '5' and SUBSTR(FIELD2, 1,3)='999'). 
I hope is clear.